# Visual Studio crashes when editing Enum property (WPF)

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, crash

I have a custom control and inside it I have an Enum property:

```
public enum paradigms { P300, CPS };

private paradigms _selectedParadigm = paradigms.P300;
public paradigms SelectedParadigm
{
    get { return _selectedParadigm; }
    set { SelectedParadigm = value; }
}
```

If I add this control to my window, in the properties window I can see this property and if I click on it I can see the available options (CSP and P300) but as soon as I choose one, Visual Studio crashes with no useful information.

I tried initializing the private variable as = `private paradigms _selectedParadigm = new paradigms();` but it makes Visual Studio crash.

I've tried with other properties, or adding a bool, and I get a nice CheckBox that I can check and uncheck and nothing crashes.

Any idea why Visual Studio crashes this way when using enum?

Note: VS 2010 Profesional

Comment: what version of visual studio are you using?

Comment: I added to the question, it is Visual Studio 2010 profesional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public paradigms SelectedParadigm
{
    get { return _selectedParadigm; }
    set { SelectedParadigm = value; }
}
```

That code causes `StackOverflowException` - which will bring down the process. Change that code to:

```
public paradigms SelectedParadigm
{
    get { return _selectedParadigm; }
    set { _selectedParadigm = value; }
}
```

Comment: dammit .. it feels like I live in a continuous sleepy Monday.. Thanks!